# web app started by jetty runner not working with jstl tags?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jetty, embedded-jetty

Used this command to start the web app using jetty-runner `java -jar prject123/web/target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar project123/web/target/*.war`

The jstl code I have is as simple as this: `<c:out value="hi there"></c:out>`, the source code I get from the rendered web page is `<c:out value></c:out>` so seems that the jstl tags are completed unparsed .

I should mention that other than using jetty-runner, other ways to start the web app seems to work well with jstl tag, for example `mvn -pl project123/web jetty:run-exploded`

I have been really struggling with this issue. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

To answer Daniel's questions: 
I am using 8.1.0.RC4 for jetty-runner and maven jetty plugin. Also I have included jstl 1.2 in my pom file.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the jsp page source code is

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!!</h1> <c:out value="you!"> </c:out>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use the same version of jetty-runner as the maven-jetty-plugin? Might be an old jetty-runner you are using. Can you paste in an example JSP page and dependencies in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java --lib  project123/web/$PATH_TO_THE_LIB -jar prject123/web/target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar project123/web/target/*.war`

--lib tells jetty runner to load the jars in the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need the standard taglibs dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and maybe change the jstl dependency to javax.servlet?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

those who ran into this question/answer while looking for jstl issues, the following link could be helpful. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP